# Altair - Plot Number of Stars/Rating (starting from bar or point graph)

Tags: python, bar-chart, altair

I am plotting a bar graph using Altair. However, instead of having the bar, I was hoping to have the number of stars (i.e. the symbol). In my case, this data is the rating (from 1 start up to 5 stars) of, for example, a movie. Checking their documentation, I see a similar idea being used [here](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/isotype.html), however, it does seem a pretty tricky path for simply plotting rating.

I am plotting my graph like this (please, not that it you can change from bar to a point graph simply replacing `mark_bar` by `mark_point`):

```
chart = (
    alt.Chart(df)
    .mark_bar()
    .encode(
        x=alt.X(
            "fund:O",
            axis=alt.Axis(title=None, labels=False, ticks=False, labelOverlap="greedy"),
        ),
        y=alt.Y("value:Q", axis=alt.Axis(title="Value", grid=True, tickMinStep=1)),
        color=alt.Color(
            "fund:N",
            legend=alt.Legend(orient="top", labelLimit=700, direction="vertical"),
        ),
        shape=alt.Shape("value:N"),
        tooltip=["fund:N", "value", "bucket", "as of"],
        column=alt.Column(
            "bucket:N",
            header=alt.Header(title=None, labelOrient="bottom", labelAngle=x_angle),
            spacing=50,
        ),
    )
    .configure_view(stroke="transparent")
    .interactive()
)
```

Which will produce this graph:
[image]

I was hoping to replace each bar with a number of stars (i.e. 4, 4, 2, and 2 stars)

Answer (score 0):

You could combine this example with a [custom SVG path string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths) to create a star shape (since it is not supported out of the box, like triangles, diamonds, etc):

```
import altair as alt
import pandas as pd

source = pd.DataFrame(
    {"data":[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
             2,2,2,
             3,3,
             4,4,4,4,4,4]
    }
)

star_shape = 'M 0.5,0.05 0.2,0.9 0.95,0.3 0.05,0.3 0.8,0.9 Z'
alt.Chart(source).mark_point(shape=star_shape, size=200).transform_window(
    id='rank()',
    groupby=['data']
).encode(
    alt.X('data:O'),
    alt.Y('id:O').axis(None).sort('descending')
)
```

[image]

More details in [the docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/generated/core/altair.MarkDef.html#altair-markdef):

[image]